# Why does Databinding is not giving proper exception?

Tags: android, android-databinding

```
error: package ViewModel does not exist
public abstract void setLoginViewModel(@Nullable ViewModel.LoginViewModel LoginViewModel);
```

error no:  It is showing error in ActivityMainBinding.java 16 no. line which is "import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel;"

How can I solve the above exception while working with DataBindings?

What I tried:

- Invalidate cache / restart
- Recheck XML attributes
- Rename small letter package name
- --debug --stacktrace build with gradle

Nothing is working. No other solution on google, StackOverflow and Youtube is working.

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel;
```

**MainActivity**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.Model.LoginUser;
import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.R;
import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel.LoginViewModel;
import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;


import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer<LoginUser> {

    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this).get(LoginViewModel.class);

        // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class.
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);

        // Specify the current activity as the lifecycle owner.
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);
        loginViewModel.getUser().observe(MainActivity.this, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginUser loginUser) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(loginUser).getEmail())) {
            binding.emailId.setError("Email Id can't be blank");
            binding.emailId.requestFocus();
        } else if (!loginUser.isEmailValid()) {
            binding.emailId.setError("Please enter valid Email Id");
            binding.emailId.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(loginUser).getPassword())) {
            binding.password.setError("Password can't be blank");
            binding.password.requestFocus();
        } else if (!loginUser.isPasswordLengthGreaterThan5()) {
            binding.password.setError("Password length must be at least 8 digit");
            binding.password.requestFocus();
        } else {
            binding.fetchEmailId.setText(loginUser.getEmail());
            binding.fetchPassword.setText(loginUser.getPassword());
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="LoginViewModel"
            type="com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".View.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                android:text="Login Example Using MVVM, DataBinding with LiveData"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-Mail Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="@={LoginViewModel.email}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/heading" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:text="@={LoginViewModel.password}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_id" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> LoginViewModel.onClick(v)}"
                android:text="Click to Login"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="See the Results Below From LiveDataBinding"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fetch_email_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="---"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fetch_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:text="---"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fetch_email_id" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

LoginViewModel:

```
    package com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel;

    import android.view.View;

    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

    import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.Model.LoginUser;

    public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

        public MutableLiveData<String> email = new MutableLiveData<>();
        public MutableLiveData<String> password = new MutableLiveData<>();
        private MutableLiveData<LoginUser> userMutableLiveData;

        public MutableLiveData<LoginUser> getUser() {
            if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
                userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            }
            return userMutableLiveData;
        }

         public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser(email.getValue(), password.getValue());
            userMutableLiveData.setValue(loginUser);
        }
    }
```

NOTE:

I'll change package name to small letter like this  viewmodel, it'll give error to ActivityMainImpl which is not generated by me

Comment: when AS show error see and check the xml tree inside error log expand `xml tree` and see line number that causing error. data binding error is shown in `XML`

Comment: can you tell if you have a package name `ViewModel` or is it `viewmodel` ?

Comment: @hasanhasan Nope. It is showing error in ActivityMainBinding.java 16 no. line which is "import com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel;"

Comment: @SomeshKumar it's a ViewModel because now if I'll change to viewmodel, it'll give error to ActivityMainImpl which is not generated by me.

Comment: post your viewModel class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have defined the package name inside your XML file with a capital letter.

```
   <variable
        name="LoginViewModel"
        type="com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel.LoginViewModel" />
```

It should be `com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.viewmodel.LoginViewModel` . `viewmodel` with the small letters and also make sure that you have the package name as `viewmodel`.

Comment: it is in capital letter only

Comment: even if I move that class to main package, it gives me error in ActivityMainImpl class

Comment: `ActivityMainImpl` is generated class clean and rebuild project. It will create new ActivityMainImpl class as per  new changes

Comment: You don't need to move to this class. just make sure package name does not have capital letters anywhere and the name should be same in the layout file and rebuild project after that It will be solved.

Comment: @DipaliSingh My intention was not to get the right tick mark but to understand why it was not working and another answer was working for you.

Comment: hehe okay okay. Thanks n keep helping me :P

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `type="com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.ViewModel.LoginViewModel"`

Any parent package must start with `lowercase` but in your case `package name` is in `Uppercase`

so rename your `ViewModel` to this `viewmodel`

Your `type` should be look like this

```
 type="com.jimmytrivedi.learning.mvvmloginsignupdemo.viewmodel.LoginViewModel"
```

Comment: If I do rename package, it gived me an error in ActivityMainImpl which is a non user class.

Comment: I wonder why this answer was selected and not mine @DipaliSingh